# Using libmms with Objective-C

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c

I've been looking for a few days around the internet for tutorials or examples on how to use libmms. There seems to be none, which is strange for a lib thats seems to be widely used.

LibMMS is a common library for parsing mms:// and mmsh:// type network streams.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmms/files/libmms/0.6.2/libmms-0.6.2.tar.gz/download

The only code sample I found was from another post on stackoverflow.

Which is will show below.

```
mms_connect(NULL, NULL, g_tcUrl.av_val, g_hostname.av_val, g_playpath.av_val, "", g_port, 128*1024)
```

Note:

```
NSString* strTemp;      
strTemp = @"mms://123.30.49.85/htv2";
// strTemp = @"mms://212.58.251.92/wms/bbc_ami/radio1/radio1_bb_live_int_eq1_sl0";
g_tcUrl.av_val = new char[[strTemp length] + 1];
[strTemp getCString:g_tcUrl.av_val
          maxLength:([strTemp length]+1)
           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
g_tcUrl.av_len = strlen(g_tcUrl.av_val);
//strTemp = @"212.58.251.92";
strTemp = @"123.30.49.85";
g_hostname.av_val = new char[[strTemp length]+1];       
[strTemp getCString:g_hostname.av_val
          maxLength:([strTemp length]+1)
           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
g_hostname.av_len = strlen(g_hostname.av_val);
//strTemp = @"/wms/bbc_ami/radio1/radio1_bb_live_int_eq1_sl0";
strTemp = @"/htv2";
g_playpath.av_val = new char[[strTemp length] + 1];         
[strTemp getCString:g_playpath.av_val
          maxLength:([strTemp length]+1)
           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
g_playpath.av_len = strlen(g_playpath.av_val);
g_port = 1755;
```

This is not objective C, but does show what needs to be passed into the mms_connect method.

So i made a new project, included all the needed libmms files and built it. Compiled ok.

The next step was to include the

```
#import "mms.h"
#import "mms_config.h"
```

and declare

```
mms_t *mms = 0;
```

No problems so far.

Next thing i wanted to try was to call the mms_connect method and here is where i get stuck.

I'm not a C programmer so this might look FUBAR but was my best attempt.
I cannot use the

```
char *g_tcUrl = new char[[strTemp length] + 1];
```

because new is not recognized in objective c in the way its used here. What should I be using to achieve the same effect in Objective-C?

```
mms_t *mms = 0;

NSString* strTemp;      
strTemp = @"mms://123.30.49.85/htv2";

char *g_tcUrl = new char[[strTemp length] + 1];
[strTemp getCString:g_tcUrl maxLength:([strTemp length]+1) 
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

strTemp = @"123.30.49.85";
char *g_hostname = new char[[strTemp length]+1];       
[strTemp getCString:g_hostname maxLength:([strTemp length]+1) 
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

strTemp = @"/htv2";
char * g_playpath = new char[[strTemp length] + 1];         
[strTemp getCString:g_playpath maxLength:([strTemp length]+1) 
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
int g_port = 1755;

//mms = mms_connect(mms_io_t *io, void *data, const char *url, const char *host, 
const char *uri, const char *query, int port, int bandwidth);
mms = mms_connect(NULL, NULL, g_tcUrl, g_hostname, g_playpath, "", g_port, 
128*1024);
```

Now I'm trying to mix in C code inside objective-c files. That code was all inside my viewDidLoad as I try and test and figure out how exactly to use libmms.

Guys I'd appreciate all advise and help you can offer in my quest to get libmms working in my app.

-Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest version I can think of:

```
// wherever these NSStrings come from in the app, we can use them
NSString *mmsURL = @"mms://123.30.49.85/htv2",
         *mmsHostname = @"123.30.49.85",
         *mmsPath = @"/htv2";
NSInteger port = 1755;

mms_t *mms = mms_connect(NULL, NULL,
                         [mmsURL cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                         [mmsHostname cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                         [mmsPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                         "", port, 128*1024);
```

To get data moving the other way too (if you want to pass stream data into a custom `AVPlayer`-based movie player or similar):

```
char *myCString = "some data coming from libmms";
NSString *myStringFromACString = 
[NSString stringWithCString:myCString
              usingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: It needs to be an ASCII string not a UTF8String.

Comment: @RTS, UTF8 is in fact fully ASCII-compatible. If you have an ASCII string and wish to decode it using UTF8, there is not a single code point which will not be correctly translated. The other way around, however, will give you errors, since ASCII cannot represent a UTF8 code point above 255. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF8#Design You should note here that one of UTF-8's design objectives was to be backwards-compatible with ASCII.

Comment: @darvids0n not quite, it is compatible with the characters that use the first 7 bits of ASCII, that is the first 127 characters. That means the other 128 characters will break the encoding. Some notable ones are... ñ,¡,Ó,¢,®,ú,µ,Ý,÷(divide sign), so it will mess up on most symbols and will screw up on different languages, while still working fine in plain english.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII You're talking about Extended ASCII, not ASCII. ASCII only defines 128 code points. My statement about code points above 255 was incorrect, it should have read 127. In either case, I'll update my answer, but you shouldn't be so quick to downvote for something like this.

Comment: From the wikipedia article for Extended ASCII (no citation): "UTF-8 is true extended ASCII, since all ASCII bytes are always interpreted as themselves, making it easier to introduce Unicode into existing systems using extended ASCII." It seems they accounted for this. I'll try and track down the source for that.

Comment: I have changed my vote since you have updated your answer, the reason for the down vote was because a bug like this one would be flat out difficult to find in a codebase. Especially one in a language you are not familiar with. When you get bug reports about people not being able to say words with accents like voilà.

Comment: From Apple Docs, the description of `NSUTF8StringEncoding` (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSUTF8StringEncoding): "An 8-bit representation of Unicode characters, suitable for transmission or storage by ASCII-based systems."

Comment: Thankyou. I do appreciate you pointing it out though, it could have been a nasty one if it were a matter of incompatibility.

Answer (score 4):

You can mix C++ and Objective-C in the same file.  Either give the file a .mm extension or by change the file type to sourcecode.cpp.objcpp.

Answer (score 1):

You're making things overly complicated. You do not have to use new here.

```
mms_t *mms = 0;
const char* g_tcUrl = "mms://123.30.49.85/htv2"; // Easy C String,
                                                 // No need for heap allocation.
const char* g_hostname = "123.30.49.85";       
const char* g_playpath = "/htv2";         

int g_port = 1755;

//mms = mms_connect(mms_io_t *io, void *data, const char *url, const char *host, const char *uri, const char *query, int port, int bandwidth);
mms = mms_connect(NULL, NULL, g_tcUrl, g_hostname, g_playpath, "", g_port, 
128*1024);
```

Also new is not a part of C. It is part of C++, in C you must use malloc to allocate memory on the heap.

Comment: An alternative way is to grab a C-string version of an existing Objective-C string (for example, if you want to store your mms connection options/parameters in a property list and read it at startup). For that: `const char *mmsURL = [myObjCString UTF8String];`

Comment: While this is true, C-strings are usually encoded in ASCII not utf8, so you would want to use `const char* mmsURL = [myObjCString cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];` UTF8 is only partially compatible with ASCII.